# Docker Run Rust Project Image Failed with WSL Error

Tags: docker, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to implement a Rust application inside of a Docker Container running in WSL.  I am new to Docker and would appreciate any help.  I need to be able to receive packets on a tcp connection on port 1883.

I am running WSL on Ubuntu and in WSL version 2.

I have been able to build the Docker Image successfully using the following Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.

ARG RUST_VERSION=1.73.0
ARG APP_NAME=service_logic
FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-slim-bullseye AS build
ARG APP_NAME
WORKDIR /service_logic

# Build the application.
# Leverage a cache mount to /usr/local/cargo/registry/
# for downloaded dependencies and a cache mount to /app/target/ for 
# compiled dependencies which will speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to the src directory to avoid having to copy the
# source code into the container. Once built, copy the executable to an
# output directory before the cache mounted /app/target is unmounted.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=service_logic,target=service_logic \
    --mount=type=bind,source=/service_logic/Cargo.toml,target=/service_logic/Cargo.toml \
    --mount=type=bind,source=/service_logic/Cargo.lock,target=/service_logic/Cargo.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/service_logic/target/ \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry/ \
    <<EOF
set -e
cargo build --locked --release
cp service_logic/target/release/$APP_NAME.exe /bin/server
EOF

################################################################################
# Create a new stage for running the application that contains the minimal
# runtime dependencies for the application. This often uses a different base
# image from the build stage where the necessary files are copied from the build
# stage.
#
# The example below uses the debian bullseye image as the foundation for running the app.
# By specifying the "bullseye-slim" tag, it will also use whatever happens to be the
# most recent version of that tag when you build your Dockerfile. If
# reproducability is important, consider using a digest
# (e.g., debian@sha256:ac707220fbd7b67fc19b112cee8170b41a9e97f703f588b2cdbbcdcecdd8af57).
FROM debian:bullseye-slim AS final

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

# Copy the executable from the "build" stage.
COPY --from=build /bin/server /service_logic/

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 1883

# What the container should run when it is started.
CMD ["service_logic/server"]
```

And after building with the following command:

`docker buildx build --tag docker-rust-image .`

I ran the image with this command:

`docker run docker-rust-image`

And got the following error:

`<3>WSL (1) ERROR: ConfigInitializeEntry:1554: Failed to mount (null) at /dev as devtmpfs 1`

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been enlisting ChatGPT to help and it says the error is something about the interaction between Docker and WSL, but I haven't gotten anywhere with any of its suggestions.

I have tried restarting both Docker and WSL multiple times. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling WSL.  All of these attempts resulted in the same error.

`<3>WSL (1) ERROR: ConfigInitializeEntry:1554: Failed to mount (null) at /dev as devtmpfs 1`

I was expecting the error to either be resolved or changed into a different error that could allow me to make other changes.

Comment: `cp service_logic/target/release/$APP_NAME.exe /bin/server` - this one seems odd to me, Docker is linux based and doesn't have `.exe` files.

Comment: I have strong doubts that the Dockerfile you provided actually produces said error. You claim that the error happens when you `docker run` - however, I already get many errors when I `docker buildx`. Your `--mount` arguments make no sense. You cp an `.exe` which does not exist on linux. After fixing those issues, it simply works for me (using a hello world application)

Comment: That said, even if it works, your binary will have dynamic dependencies which might break when transferring it from the `build` to the `final` docker container. So for this usecase, it is recommended to use the `musl` target, which builds a static executable. To do so, use `FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build` instead of `slim`. If you do this or not of course depends on your project and you might have to experiment around a little.

Comment: But back to your actual problem: I suspect that there's something wrong with your docker installation in WSL. How did you install it? I did so by [enabling systemd in `/etc/wsl.conf`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/) and then I installed `apt install docker.io`. This is the only reliably way I found so far. Using the windows docker passed into WSL absolutely did not work for me at all, which is what I suspect you did, as you have a `.exe` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: If this suspicion of mine is correct, then I recommend the following steps:
1) Uninstall docker from Windows. 2) [Enable systemd in /etc/wsl.conf](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/). 3) Install docker inside of WSL again with `apt update && apt install docker.io`.

Comment: The last step that might then be missing is that you add yourself to the `docker` group in WSL so you can use it without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that you can restart Docker separately from WSL, which indicates to me that you are using the Windows based docker mapped into WSL. This is the 'official' solution from docker, and it absolutely never worked for me properly. Maybe this changes in the future, but for now, I strongly recommend using the Linux based docker **inside** of WSL instead.

To achieve this, I recommend the following:

- Uninstall the Windows based Docker
- [Enable systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/) in WSL, which is required to run the docker service inside of the WSL:

  - Add the following to `/etc/wsl.conf`:

    ```
    [boot]
    systemd=true
    ```
  - Reboot your WSL by running the following in a Powershell:

    ```
    wsl.exe --shutdown
    ```
- Install Docker inside of WSL by running:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install docker.io
  ```
- Add yourself to the `docker` group to allow using `docker` without `sudo`:

  ```
  usermod -a -G docker <your-username>
  ```
- Reboot your WSL again by running the following in a Powershell:

  ```
  wsl.exe --shutdown
  ```

Then, the `docker` command should be available again inside of WSL and work properly, now completely Linux based, as intended. This should potentially get rid of your problem.

---

Further, there are a couple of mistakes in your Dockerfile:

- Your `--mount`s are all over the place, some of them `/service_logic`, some of them `service_logic`. You need to make them more consistent.
- You copy an `.exe` file - this is probably a leftover from your Windows based Docker. Linux executables do not have `.exe` file endings.

Further, you use `-slim` for building. This will create a dynamic executable (which you can check with `CMD ["ldd", "service_logic/server"]`). This might break when copying the binary from the `build` container to the `final` container. It is recommended to build a static executable instead, which you can do with `FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build` (`rust:alpine` is based on the `musl` target).

With all that, the following works for me with in WSL2 in Win11 and Ubuntu 22.04:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.

ARG RUST_VERSION=1.73.0
ARG APP_NAME=service_logic
FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build
ARG APP_NAME
WORKDIR /service_logic

# Build the application.
# Leverage a cache mount to /usr/local/cargo/registry/
# for downloaded dependencies and a cache mount to /app/target/ for
# compiled dependencies which will speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to the src directory to avoid having to copy the
# source code into the container. Once built, copy the executable to an
# output directory before the cache mounted /app/target is unmounted.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=service_logic,target=/service_logic \
    --mount=type=bind,source=service_logic/Cargo.toml,target=/service_logic/Cargo.toml \
    --mount=type=bind,source=service_logic/Cargo.lock,target=/service_logic/Cargo.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/service_logic/target/ \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry/ \
    <<EOF
set -e
cargo build --locked --release
cp /service_logic/target/release/$APP_NAME /bin/server
EOF

################################################################################
# Create a new stage for running the application that contains the minimal
# runtime dependencies for the application. This often uses a different base
# image from the build stage where the necessary files are copied from the build
# stage.
#
# The example below uses the debian bullseye image as the foundation for running the app.
# By specifying the "bullseye-slim" tag, it will also use whatever happens to be the
# most recent version of that tag when you build your Dockerfile. If
# reproducability is important, consider using a digest
# (e.g., debian@sha256:ac707220fbd7b67fc19b112cee8170b41a9e97f703f588b2cdbbcdcecdd8af57).
FROM debian:bullseye-slim AS final

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

# Copy the executable from the "build" stage.
COPY --from=build /bin/server /service_logic/

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 1883

# What the container should run when it is started.
CMD ["service_logic/server"]
```

```
$ cargo new service_logic
$ docker buildx build --tag docker-rust-image .
$ docker run docker-rust-image
Hello, world!
```